# DateField impossible to add without providing default

Tags: python, django, django-models

My two applications are linked by a many-to-many relationship:

Account app models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

Images app models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify


class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                              related_name='images_created',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='images_liked',
                                        blank=True)
```

When I do `python manage.py makemigrations`, terminal shows:

> It is impossible to add the field 'created' with 'auto_now_add=True' to image without providing a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
>  1) Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
>  2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

When I choose 1:

> Please enter the default value as valid Python.
> Accept the default 'timezone.now' by pressing 'Enter' or provide another value.
> The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.

But `timezone.now` doesn't help. Terminal printed:

> It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'image' to image without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
> Please select a fix
> 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
> 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

I tried `created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, default=0)`:

> ERRORS:
> images.Image.created: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.

`"blank=True, null=True"` for this field doesn't help either. I tried `created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)` and of course to delete database.

Django is v4.1.10. To populate existing rows which do I need to fill in?

Comment: First statement about `timezone.now` not helping is wrong, because it's followed by unrelated to it issue with different field, for second case warning is self-explanatory, just remove `default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set 'null=True' for your 'created' field in Image class

```
 created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

this allows the 'created' field to be null for existing rows during the migration

you can also use timezone as a default:

```
from django.utils import timezone

created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

I hope this helps you.